# Online stock brokers for LSE or TWSE?

Tags: stock-exchanges, online-brokerage

Which online stock brokers allow trading on the London or Taiwan Stock Exchanges?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interactive Brokers definitely let you trade in London

http://www.interactivebrokers.com/en/general/whyib/PDF-GlobalOfferings.php